# Linux Kernel Dev - cgroup - How to list tasks' id from a group?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cgroups

I'm developping a kernel module and I'd like to be able to list tasks' id from a group.

For example: I create two groups in the cpuset subsys: A and B. In B/tasks I put a PID. From my module, I'm getting a pointer to the subsys cgroup (`&top_cpuset.css` for exemple) and I iterate over its children (here, A and B thanks to `struct list_head children;` in the `struct cgroup_subsys_state`).

What I miss is a way from children to list the tasks.

In `struct cgroup` (accessible thanks to `struct cgroup_subsys_state`) there is this field: `struct list_head pidlists`. There is a `struct cgroup_pidlists` but it looks like this structure and its functions are internals to cgroup and are not intended to be used (static functions, structure and enum defined in a .c file no .h).

Also in the `struct css_set` there is this field `struct list_head tasks;`. But I don't find a path from `struct cgroup` or `struct cgroup_subsys_state` to `struct css_set`.

I have no more idea on what I can do to list the different tasks of a group. Any idea?

Edit: I'm modifying a Linux 5.7.0

Edit 2:

From `struct task_struct` there is the `struct nsproxy *nsproxy;` field. Which gives access to `struct cgroup_namespace *cgroup_ns;` field. Which gives an access to the `struct css_set *root_cset` where there is the `struct list_head tasks`.

But my problem remains the same. Above the `struct list_head tasks`, there is this comment "Lists running through all tasks using this cgroup group". But I don't understand how to choose the cgroup group. I mean, a task can be in different cgroup groups. How can get the `struct list_head tasks` of a specific group.

Comment: Do you want to know the groups given a task, or do you want to know the tasks in a group given the group? Your title says 1 but your final question says 2. Those are completely different scenarios, you should clarify which one you need.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my title and my post. Thank you.